# How do I resolve a "rm: libtoolT: No such file or directory" error?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I'm doing a "portmaster -f" update on a machine just upgraded from FreeBSD 8.3 to 9.1 and am getting a "rm: libtoolT: No such file or directory" error.  I see it's something that commonly afflicts Debian Linux distros, so I tried that fix (of adding a -f flag to the RM definition for the m4 processor).  I also forced an autotool update and re-ran portmaster, same problem though.  What should I try next?

Comment: As a side note, a fresh install and update of FreeBSD 9.1 ports fails in exactly the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not happen when doing an upgrade to FreeBSD 9.2.  Abandoning FreeBSD 9.1 for 9.2.